# Neo4j Spring Data GraphRepository param list

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I'm trying to do a Cypher IN query, using neo4j, spring data graph repository

public interface StuffRepository extends GraphRepository {

```
Vote findByUniqueKey(String uniqueKey);

@Query(value = "MATCH (Stuff)" +
        "USING INDEX n:Vote(uniqueKey)" +
        "WHERE n.uniqueKey IN {keys}" +
        "RETURN n")
List<Stuff> findAllWithKeys(@Param("keys") List<String> keys);
```

}

from the logs i can see that the generated query looks like:

MATCH (n:Stuff)
USING INDEX n:Stuff(uniqueKey)
WHERE n.uniqueKey IN {keys}
RETURN n

params {keys=['key1', 'key2']}

(thats how it logs anyway - I know the params are not passed like that in the cypher)

if I copy the query from the logs and run it without using the params:

MATCH (n:Stuff)
USING INDEX n:Stuff(uniqueKey)
WHERE n.uniqueKey IN ['key1', 'key2']
RETURN n

It works, and returns me my 2 'Stuff', but from my repository query I am getting back zero results.

Any ideas why params is not working as I'd expect for Cypher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try a string[] instead, might be a bug in parameter conversion. If so please raise a jira issue.

Comment: Thanks for getting back, I've tried with String[], but the params logged now have an ugly toString()

                                                               o.s.d.n.r.SpringRestCypherQueryEngine    : Executing remote cypher query: MATCH (n:Stuff)
USING INDEX n:Stuff(uniqueKey)
WHERE n.uniqueKey IN {keys}
RETURN n params {keys=[Ljava.lang.String;@1aaada09}                                                  

and still zero results. Do you think this is a bug then? Shall I riase a jira?